# Corrupt Query String: "80" being removed by IIS?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-6

I've been fighting this problem for a few days now, and can't seem to figure out what is causing it.

I have a registration system that requires activation.  An email is sent to the user with a hash that is passed back to the server when they click the activation link.  Pretty basic stuff.  The link looks something like this:

`http://site/activate.aspx?activationKey=26a51d9eba86c73b8f7e800c41bf55453ed3b1c4`

While developing on my local machine (running VS2010), this works flawlessly.  However, when the site is pushed to the live server (IIS 6), the query string is being mangled, presumably by IIS.  Once the query string hits the code-behind, any occurrence of "80" has been stripped away, causing the activation to fail.

I've wondered whether this is an encoding/decoding problem, but none of the characters are special, so I don't think that should be the case.

Comment: Is there some "rewrite" left in by an admin or person who thought they should be an admin? (Perhaps in some misguided attempt to remove port numbers...) Are there any proxy servers between? What does IIS show the full request is IN THE LOG? What happens if "80" is part of the path itself (not query string)? Are you sure you aren't mucking with the query-string somewhere? A forgotten handler? There is nothing "standard" that will break as described.

Comment: Instead of testing on Web Server provided by VS2010, try IIS itself. And for debugging, attach to w3wp.exe

Comment: Just got through digging through the IIS logs.  You're onto something.

Again, here's the original query:
`Activate.aspx?activationKey=26a51d9eba86c73b8f7e800c41bf55453ed3b1c4`

And it's showing up in the IIS log as: 
`Activate.aspx?activationKey=26a51d9eba86c73b8f7e0c41bf55453ed3b1c4`

Notice that the "80" is gone.  Now, given that I'm a Linux man (and IIS is a bit foreign to me), if it's showing up in the log like that, is it being altered _before_ or _after_ it's getting to IIS?  In other words, some setting in IIS isn't causing this, it's something before it reaches IIS.

Comment: You might need to install `Wireshark` and have a look at the packet requests (you may need to be running against something other than your local pc to test though) http://www.wireshark.org/download.html

Comment: I plan to do some more investigation with Wireshark today.  Last night I was more concerned with just creating a workaround for the problem, since it was on a production server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I found the problem.  @pst and @Mikael Eliasson were right, some goon did have some some rewrite rules in place, in a sense.

The site is forced into SSL by redirecting a 403;4 error to another (pre-existing) app that rewrites the URL to use HTTPS.  In a sense, you can force SSL on an app, and the rest is (broken) magic.  Here's the original code:

```
if ( Request.ServerVariables[ "SERVER_PORT" ] == "80" ) {
    try {
        string queryString, secureURL;

        queryString = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.ToString();
        queryString = Request.ServerVariables[ "QUERY_STRING" ];
        Response.Write( queryString + "<br>" );

        secureURL = queryString.Replace( "http", "https" );
        secureURL = secureURL.Replace( "403;", "" );
        secureURL = secureURL.Replace( "80", "" );

        Response.Write( secureURL );
        Response.Redirect( secureURL );
    }
    catch ( Exception ex ) {
    }
}
```

Note the brutal replacement of "80" in there.  Changing that replacement to ":80" fixes the problem, assuming I don't pass a query string with ":80" in it, which I won't.

Thanks for at least pointing me in the right direction, guys.

Answer (score 2):

I know for a fact that IIS does not remove 80 from the querystring by default. I have had it in querystrings many times on my sites without any problems.

Look through the IIS for url-rewrite rules. I'm not sure if the IIS-log will use the final url or the url before IIS. But considering it's 80 I guess someone want to remove port 80 from urls but has added a faulty rewrite rule for this.

So I would look for a place where someone could have tried to strip port 80 from urls. Could be in IIS or upstream.

Answer (score 1):

turn on trace.axd on the website and check what the values are being sent across. Are you sure that the email client is not doing anything

Comment: Pretty sure.  I've tried it from multiple places (Gmail in multiple browsers, Outlook, and pasting the URL directly into the address bar).  It's still working perfectly on my development machine, so I'm thinking it has to be something on the production server.